# Работа с Properties в текущей сборке проекта

Tags: c#, .net, properties

В "Обозревателе решений" в конкретном проекте есть папка с гаечным ключом - `Properties`.
Внутри нее созданы папки с произвольным именем внутри которых лежат файлы с расширением **.settings**.
Сейчас, что обратиться к свойству пишу так:
`Properties.Application.<name_file.settings>.Default[name] = value;`
Следовательно, я принудительно задаю куда записывать значение.
В методе, где это использую добавил переменную `string`, которая содержит имя. 
Но не могу понять как сделать, что бы было вот так:
`Properties.Application.from.Default[name] = value;`,
 где `from` - переменная.

Comment: Именно такой синтаксис невозможен. Однако, зачем несколько файлов? Неужто настроек так много?

Comment: Хотелось не писать всё в одно место, а логически разделить. Например настройки пользователя (внешний вид, язык, пути) и например параметры соединения с БД